# Фатальная ошибка SDL2

Tags: windows-10, haskell, стек, sdl2, msys2

> *..Проблема чисто техническая*

Месяца два назад всё работало, я следовал инструкции [первой](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskellgamedev/comments/4jpthu/windows_sdl2_is_now_almost_painless_via_stack/) и [второй](https://www.cyberforum.ru/haskell/thread1982908.html).

Сейчас, после установки `ghc-9.2.5`, при добавлении `sdl2` в `package.yaml > dependencies` проекта вылезает длиннющий адрес, и такой вот тип ошибки:

`Error: [S-7282]`

```
    Stack failed to execute the build plan.
    While executing the build plan, Stack encountered the following errors:
    <stderr>: commitAndReleaseBuffer: invalid argument (invalid character)
```

*{-PS. Я понимаю что все ошибки возникают из-за элементарных проблем, я точно где-то ступил, надежд в этом году не питаю, но в следующем бросать пройденный путь сквозь рукава не собираюсь. Но я точно помню, что похожая ошибка возникала и при её переустановках-}*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась очень забавной, её решение лежало в ручном определении предыдущего, и установленного по умолчанию *[в C:\sr\global-project\stack.yaml]* lts в `stack.yaml > resolver` каждого нужного проекта

> ох уж этот ghc и lts, голову мне морочат